# Movie won't run in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, movie15

i'am trying to include a video into my beamer-präsentation. The picture and the buttons are displayed, but the video won't run. Im using iOS, just in case there is a special problem with my platform. Thank you for your time :)

```
    \begin{frame}{Snake-Lichtspiel}
    \begin{center}
    \movie[width = 6cm, hight = 6cm, start = 0s, duration = 15s]{\includegraphics[width = 6cm, hight = 6cm]{../Images/P1080386}}{../Videos/snake.mp4}
    \\
    \hyperlinkmovie[start = 15s, duration = 20s]{snake}
    {\beamerbutton{Snake}}
    \hyperlinkmovie[pause]{snake}{\beamerbutton{pause}}
    \hyperlinkmovie[resume]{snake}{\beamerbutton{resume}}
  \end{center}
 \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [`movie15`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/movie15) is obsolete since several years ago. It is superseded by the [`media9`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/media9) package by the same author and having similar syntax.

The following example works with Adobe Reader on Linux, Mac, and Windows, but not iOS. Embedded video is a tricky business because a flash application (SWF) is required for playback, either embedded in the PDF or downloaded at presentation run-time.

In this code, the player `VPlayer9.swf` is embedded, but this is not supported by Adobe Reader on iOS, and I haven't managed to find one that actually is. The package manual has some notes about this:

> On tablets and phones running Android or iOS, ezPDF Reader was reported to play video and sound files embedded with `media9`.

So it may be the case that this app will handle `VPlayer9.swf` as embedded in the code here. Unfortunately, that app costs money, and I don't feel like purchasing it because I won't use it more than this one-time test.<sup>1</sup>

The media files `cubeposter.png` and `cube.mp4` used for the example may be found within the `media9` package distribution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includemedia[
  addresource=cube.mp4,
  flashvars={
    source=cube.mp4
    &autoPlay=true % start playing on activation
    &loop=true
  }
]{\includegraphics{cubeposter}}{VPlayer9.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

<sup>1</sup> If anyone has an Android device and has time to test, I'd appreciate it. IIRC Google Play Store allows a trial period for purchased apps, but maybe this has changed since I was on Android.

Comment: The problem is that there is no Flash player available on mobile OSs, thanks to the ban Apple expressed on Flash a while back.

Comment: @AlexG thanks for visiting; I was hoping you would see this. Flash ban indeed! Do you know how ezPDF gets around this, or is my quote from the manual possibly no longer correct? Maybe I should just buy the app to test.

Comment: They just don't use `VPlayer.swf' or whatever video player component was embedded into the PDF alongside the MP4 file, and use some non-Flash built-in or other video player of the OS to play the video.